# Controller RSpec: test PATCH update using custom ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I’m having a challenge write a RSpec controller test for a PATCH update, because the routing and edit uses a secure `edit_id` that my model generates, instead of the standard 1,2,3,4,5 (sequenced id) that Rails auto-generates. Basically, I’m not sure how to get my tests to lookup the request to be edited using this edit_id.

My test currently:

```
describe "PATCH edit/update" do

    before :each do
        @testrequest = FactoryGirl.build(:request, name: "James Dong")
    end

    it "located the requested @testrequest" do
        patch :update, id: @testrequest.edit_id, request: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:request)
        assigns(:request).should eq(@testrequest)
    end

    describe "using valid data" do

        it "updates the request" do
            patch :update, @testrequest.name = "Larry Johnson" 
            @testrequest.reload
            @testrequest.name.should eq("Larry Johnson")
        end
    end
```

**FactoryGirl** helper (I've tried both explicitly adding edit_id and not [i.e., relying on the model to create the edit_id itself], neither makes a difference) code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :request do |f|
        f.name { Faker::Name.name }
        f.email { Faker::Internet.email }
        f.item { "random item" }
        f.detail { "random text" }
        f.edit_id { "random" }
    end
end
```

**Controller**:

```
def update
    @request = Request.find_by_edit_id(params[:edit_id])
    if @request.update_attributes(request_params) 
    flash[:success] = "Your request has been updated! We'll respond within one business day."
    redirect_to edit_request_path(@request.edit_id)
    else
    render 'edit'
    end
end
```

**Routing**:

```
get 'edit/:edit_id', to: 'requests#edit', as: 'edit_request'
patch 'requests/:edit_id', to: 'requests#update', as: 'request'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok someone helped me figure this out, and I feel very silly. The "id" that you pass to the patch method can be any id, so instead of trying to set id: edit_it, I should use edit_it in the first place. I.e., the code that works:

```
before :each do
    @testrequest = FactoryGirl.build(:request, name: "James Dong")
end

it "located the requested @testrequest" do
    patch :update, edit_id: @testrequest.edit_id, request: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:request)
    assigns(:request).should eq(@testrequest)
end

describe "using valid data" do

    it "updates the request" do
        patch :update, edit_id: @testrequest.edit_id, request: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:request, name: "Larry Johnson")
        @testrequest.reload
        @testrequest.name.should eq("Larry Johnson")
    end
end
```